# From Python to create an alarm in Zabbix

Tags: python, zabbix

Could you please tell me how can I create an alarm from a Python script in a Zabbix system?
I have a `Python script` in which a certain function is processed, and at a certain point I would like to create an `alarm in the Zabbix system` when a certain condition is created in the script. I also have a `mail server`. I was thinking of creating a separate `mailbox for Zabbix`, to this email address I will `send` a letter from Python, and the Zabbix system will receive this letter, process and create a `Problem`. Is such functionality possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to use zabbix for this. To do that you feed values to an item in zabbix in one of the many ways and create a trigger that fires when you want it.
If a script is needed to generate the values you can implement the script as a user parameter if it is short running. If it takes more than a few seconds using zabbix sender might be smarter.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I will use utility `zabbix sender`